# why is POSIX::SigSet is needed here?

Tags: linux, perl, signals, posix

```
!/usr/bin/env perl
use POSIX;

my $sig_set = POSIX::SigSet->new(POSIX::SIGINT);
my $sig_act = POSIX::SigAction->new(sub { print "called\n"; exit 0 },$sig_set);

POSIX::sigaction(SIGINT,$sig_act);

sleep(15);
```

Why do I need to use `POSIX::SigSet` if I already tell `POSIX::sigaction` that I want `SIGINT`?

Basically I'm trying to respond with my coderef to each of the signal I add to SigSet, looking at `POSIX::sigaction` signature, it must accept a singal as the first parametner, which doesnt seems reasonable to be if I already tell `POSIX::SigAction` about my `POSIX::SigSet`.

I'm sure I am missing something here.

thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The answer to your question

The POSIX::SigSet specifies *additional signals to mask off* (to ignore) during the execution of your signal handler sub.  It corresponds to the `sa_mask` member of the underlying struct passed to the [C version of `sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html).

Now, SIGINT (well, the first argument to sigaction) will be masked off by default, unless you explicitly request otherwise via the SA_NODEFER.

### A better approach?

However, if all you want to do it to register a signal handler whose execution won't be interrupted by the signal for which it was registered (e.g., don't allow SIGINT during your SIGINT handler), you can skip the POSIX module entirely:

```
$SIG{INT} = sub { print "called\n"; exit 0; };  # Won't be interrupted by SIGINT
```

Where it can, Perl's signal dispatching emulates the traditional UNIX semantics of blocking a signal during its handler execution.  (And on Linux, it certainly can.  sigprocmask() is called before executing the handler, and then a scope-guard function is registered to re-allow that signal at the end of the user-supplied sub.)